# Positioning Multiple Colorbars outside of Subplots (matplotlib)

Tags: python, matplotlib, subplot, colorbar, imshow

I have a figure with multiple subplot rows that all share an x axis.
Some of the rows require a color bar, but the other rows don't.
If I just use the color bar function, the subplots will be misaligned.
How do I place the color bars outside of the subplots such that all the rows will still be aligned?

[image: figure with misaligned subplots]

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 3):

I made a function that may help:

```
import numpy as np
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt

#function to add colorbar for imshow data and axis
def add_colorbar_outside(im,ax):
    fig = ax.get_figure()
    bbox = ax.get_position() #bbox contains the [x0 (left), y0 (bottom), x1 (right), y1 (top)] of the axis.
    width = 0.01
    eps = 0.01 #margin between plot and colorbar
    # [left most position, bottom position, width, height] of color bar.
    cax = fig.add_axes([bbox.x1 + eps, bbox.y0, width, bbox.height])
    cbar = fig.colorbar(im, cax=cax)

#Example code:
x = np.random.random((10, 100))
fig, axes = plt.subplots(5,1, sharex = True)
im = axes[0].imshow(x, cmap = "Reds", aspect="auto", origin="lower")
add_colorbar_outside(im, axes[0])
im2 = axes[2].imshow(x, cmap = "coolwarm", aspect="auto", origin="lower")
add_colorbar_outside(im2, axes[2])
plt.show()
```

[image: figure with colorbars outside]

Answer (score 0):

The `sharex=True` and `layout='constrained'` argument (as pointed out by @drmuelr) should be sufficient to solve your problem.
i.e. `fig, axes = plt.subplots(3,1, sharex = True, layout='constrained')` in your case.

Matplotlib by now has good documentation on how to arrange the colorbar here: https://matplotlib.org/stable/users/explain/axes/colorbar_placement.html

Comment: `sharex=True` on its own isn't enough; it has to be used in conjunction with `layout='constrained'`, such as `plt.subplots(3, 1, sharex=True, layout='constrained')`.